# Execute bash remotely kept returning syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have this [link](https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/NDRjMWE2MTUtOWZkMy00ZjYxLTg1YjEtOWFkZmM4ZTFmZTU1), it return raw text of this

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/home/forge/pm2020/public"
if [ -d "$PATH" ] 
then
    echo "Directory $PATH exists." 
else
    echo "Error: Directory $PATH does not exists."
fi
```

I'm wondering when I run it via cURL why do I kept getting this error

> bash: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

HTML representation of my bash script

```
<pre>#!/bin/bash
path=&quot;/home/forge/pm2020/public&quot;
if [ -d &quot;$path&quot; ] 
then
    echo &quot;Directory $path exists.&quot; 
else
    echo &quot;Error: Directory $path does not exists.&quot;
fi</pre>
```

> Do you guys think that `&quot;` is the root of the issue ?
> If so, how can I fix it ?

---

## Out of Curiousity

I even try pastebin, but uploaded my bash script [there](https://pastebin.com/raw/AhrB08Bc)

```
└── curl https://pastebin.com/raw/AhrB08Bc | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   170    0   170    0     0    301      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   301
bash: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: line 8: `fi'
```

I'm not sure what to even check anymore

Comment: Does your code have DOS-style `\r\n` line endings? If it does, `then\r` would not be seen as a keyword, so `fi` is encountered before `then`

Comment: Pick a different variable name in any case; `PATH` is already used by other commands. (In general, avoid using all-uppercase names, as they are reserved.)

Comment: Also, you aren't executing anything remotely; you are *transferring* a remote resource to your local computer and executing it *locally*.

Comment: @chepner corect! Is it possible to not store it locally or I have to ? I just don't want to leave junks behind for something that only needs to run one; that's why I build the online URL to the codes.

Comment: How do I even begin to check if I have DOS-style ? Is it something I should in PHP ? JS ? Chrome Console ? or inside the server ? Can you please provide a bt more hints pls ?

Comment: I updated PATH to path (https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/MWY5OWZiYjAtNTNkMC00MWRlLTk2NTYtNDA2ZDc5YzgwOTEz) , ran it, and still same error. I'm checking HTML now in case I send extra charactors;

Comment: Leaving junk behind is probably much safer than trusting a random online service to store code that you then download and run without any kind of signature validation. (A TLS handshake only proves you're reaching a server with pastebin.com's private keys; it doesn't prove that it's still serving the same code you uploaded -- and back in the day, pastebin.com served up some _very_ dodgy animated/javascript/&c ads; I wouldn't trust them not to bend their ethics if it would make them a buck).

Answer (score 1):

> *I have this [link](https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/NDRjMWE2MTUtOWZkMy00ZjYxLTg1YjEtOWFkZmM4ZTFmZTU1), it return raw text of this*

No it doesn't. It returns some malformed HTML:

```
<title>#!/bin/bash
PATH=&quot;/home/forge/pm2020/public&quot;
if [ -d &quot;$PATH&quot; ]
then
    echo &quot;Directory $PATH exists.&quot;
else
    echo &quot;Error: Directory $PATH does not exists.&quot;
fi</title><link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/WWWynu9.png" /><img style="display:non
e;" src="https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/welcome-jpeg"><pre>#!/bin/bash
PATH=&quot;/home/forge/pm2020/public&quot;
if [ -d &quot;$PATH&quot; ]
then
    echo &quot;Directory $PATH exists.&quot;
else
    echo &quot;Error: Directory $PATH does not exists.&quot;
fi</pre>
```

You should use an HTML-parser, like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).
`xidel` can repair this by adding a root-tag and some parent-tags:

```
$ xidel -s "https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/NDRjMWE2MTUtOWZkMy00ZjYxLTg1YjEtOWFkZmM4ZTFmZTU1" \
  -e . --output-node-format=html --output-node-indent
<html>
  <head>
    <title>#!/bin/bash
PATH="/home/forge/pm2020/public"
if [ -d "$PATH" ]
then
    echo "Directory $PATH exists."
else
    echo "Error: Directory $PATH does not exists."
fi</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://i.imgur.com/WWWynu9.png">
  </head>
  <body><img style="display:none;" src="https://www.bunlongheng.com/img/welcome-jpeg">
    <pre>#!/bin/bash
PATH="/home/forge/pm2020/public"
if [ -d "$PATH" ]
then
    echo "Directory $PATH exists."
else
    echo "Error: Directory $PATH does not exists."
fi</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

To extract the Bash-code:

```
$ xidel -s "https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/NDRjMWE2MTUtOWZkMy00ZjYxLTg1YjEtOWFkZmM4ZTFmZTU1" \
  -e '//pre'   # or in full: -e 'html/body/pre'.
               # -e '//title, or -e 'html/head/title' would work as well.
```

And as far as the line endings are concerned... this works for me to actually execute:

```
$ xidel -s "https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/NDRjMWE2MTUtOWZkMy00ZjYxLTg1YjEtOWFkZmM4ZTFmZTU1" \
  -e '//pre' | tr -d '\r' | bash
Error: Directory /home/forge/pm2020/public does not exists.
```